# C# function call with multiple generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I know that I can call a generic extension method

```
public static object Convert<U>(this U value)
```

Like this (no `<Class1>` required):

```
Class1Instance.Convert()
```

But is there a way to call :

```
public static T Convert<U, T>(this U value) 
  where T : Class1, Interface1, new()
  where U : Class1, Interface2, new()
{
  /******/
}
```

With `Class1Instance.Convert<Class2>()` "only", instead of `Class1Instance.Convert<Class1, Class2>()`

Thanks,

**EDIT :**

Reformulation / simplification : 
Is there a way to have  :

```
Result result = Convert<Result>(input);
```

Where we know input of type Input, instead of having to say

```
Result result = Convert<Input, Result>(input)
```

With an extension method which looks like this :

```
static TResult Convert<TResult, TInput>(this TInput Input)
```

Comment: Did you mean   
where T : Class1, IClass1, new()
where U : Class2, IClass2, new()
?

Comment: I believe that what he's asking is a way to call Convert and only have to specify the "result" type parameter and have the compiler infer the "input" type parameter, i.e. `Result result = Convert<Result>(input);` where we know input if of type Input, instead of having to say `Result result = Convert<Input, Result>(input)`.

Comment: If my inference is right, check this question for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354288/c-why-doesnt-generic-type-inference-work-when-there-are-multiple-type-argumen

Comment: Why would you need the `new()` constraint on the type you're converting *from*? Also, I assume `Class1` implements `IClass1`, so that constraint is redundant on both `T` and `U`.

Comment: You're right Daniel Joseph, I'll edit my post with your clarification :)

Comment: @gabba, no, my definition is right, U and T are extending /implementing the same classe/interface, but I think it's not very important in my problem

Comment: @David No, I don't need the `new` constraint, you're right. But Your second assumption is false. I will have multiple convert methods, for classes which derive from Class1, but which implements different interfaces

Comment: So `Class1` doesn't implement `IClass1`? OK, the generic constraints make sense then. (The names imply that `Class1` does implement `IClass1`, do consider using different example names next time.)

Comment: @David Yes you're right, I'll edit my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354288/c-why-doesnt-generic-type-inference-work-when-there-are-multiple-type-argumen), generic parameter inference works only with input parameters. In my case, one of the generic parameter is a return type.

As it is required that generic types inference provides all of them, I have to specify each parameter explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to call `Convert<U, T>` by specifying `Convert<Class2>` in your calling code. However, if you really want the calling code to look like that, there is a possibility.

```
public static T Convert<T>(this Class1 value) 
  where T : Class1, IClass1, new()
{ ... }
```

Instead of being generic on the input type, just specify the parent class of the input type. This will give you the calling code you want, but it will make the method more complex. For example, if the conversion process involves creating a new `U` object (making use of the `new()` generic constraint in the old method definition), then you'll have to do it with reflection in the new method.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but it's not possible in my specific case. Thanks anyway for confirming to me that it's not achievable this way.